# Why does my code cause instruction-cache misses?

Tags: c++, performance, cpu-cache

According to cachegrind this checksum calculation routine is one of the greatest contributors to instruction-cache load and instruction-cache misses in the entire application:

```
#include <stdint.h>

namespace {

uint32_t OnesComplementSum(const uint16_t * b16, int len)  {
    uint32_t sum = 0;

    uint32_t a = 0;
    uint32_t b = 0;
    uint32_t c = 0;
    uint32_t d = 0;

    // helper for the loop unrolling
    auto run8 = [&] {
        a += b16[0];
        b += b16[1];
        c += b16[2];
        d += b16[3];
        b16 += 4;
    };

    for (;;) {
        if (len > 32) {
            run8();
            run8();
            run8();
            run8();
            len -= 32;
            continue;
        }

        if (len > 8) {
            run8();
            len -= 8;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    sum += (a + b) + (c + d);

    auto reduce = [&]() {
        sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);
        if (sum > 0xFFFF) sum -= 0xFFFF;
    };

    reduce();

    while ((len -= 2) >= 0) sum += *b16++;

    if (len == -1) sum += *(const uint8_t *)b16; // add the last byte

    reduce();

    return sum;
}    

} // anonymous namespace     

uint32_t get(const uint16_t* data, int length)
{
    return OnesComplementSum(data, length);
}
```

[See asm output here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf4bc955212480b2)

Maybe the it's caused by the  loop unrolling, but the generated object code doesn't seem too excessive.

How can I improve the code?

#### Update

- **Because the checksum function was in an anonymous namespace it was inlined and duplicated by two functions that resided in the same cpp file.**
- The loop unrolling is still beneficial. Removing it slowed down the code.
- Improving the infinite loop [speeds up the code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d8ec318383d80aa) (but for some reason I get opposite results on my mac).

  - [Before fixes: here you can see the two checksums and 17210 L1 IR misses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWZuE.png)
  - [After fixes: after fixing the inlining problem and fixing the infinite loop the L1 instruction cache misses dropped to 8324.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0RBd.png)
  - "InstructionFetch" is higher in the fixed example. I'm not sure how to interpret that. Does it simply mean that's where most activity occurred? Or does it hint at a problem?

Comment: The problem is not this code, but that the caller call it with pointers that cause the misses !!

Comment: How large is your data? Note that sometimes there isn't much you can do to avoid cache-misses - you have to actually read the data into memory. And it may well be that "next time you call this function, it's no longer in cache" (or it is inlined in 11 different places, so the code is not in cache because the last call, it was a different instance)- sometimes it's better to ensure a function is NOT inlined.

Comment: The number of cache misses isn't really relevant, without knowing how often that piece of code was executed and how it was called (in a loop / from totally different points in the code?). Aside from that: Have your performed any actual measurements that show that all that manual loop unroling actually increases perfromance? Compiler are perfectly capable to unroll trivial loops themselves, if they think it would increase performance.

Comment: First, instruction cache not data folks.  Second, your loop unroll would be neater if you did the small-loop in a different loop: unless the compiler spots it (did not check asm), that seems poor.  Even if not, why not make split explicit?

Comment: @MatsPetersson The data is near 1500 bytes per call. This is the place were the program is forced to iterate over all the data, so data cache misses would not be unexpected. But I can't explain the icache misses.

Comment: What other code is executed before each call (including system calls)?

Comment: @MatsPetersson It's validating TCP header of incoming packet. Before that it was being dispatched from IP.

Comment: Any chance you can use _mm_add_epi16 to vectorize the addition? This is only portable to x86 processors (but I believe is available on all the major compilers), but is included in everything at all recent. I haven't gone through `reduce` in detail to be sure this has precisely the same semantics, but at first glance it looks like you're just producing a 16-bit unsigned result.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I should eventually look into that. The checksum performance is actually not a big issue atm. I asked this question mostly because I wanted to understand the Cachegrind report.

Comment: @Yakk Thanks for mentioning. I never noticed it was wasteful. [The performance difference is more significant than I anticipated.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d8ec318383d80aa)

Comment: Did you try writing the code cleanly and clearly first before trying to optimize it with less-frequent tests? It's probably causing instruction cache misses because your tests are unpredictable while a simple loop would get predicted correctly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It was a function from the company's legacy code which I mostly cleaned up and added improvements to.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm still learning to interpret cachegrind's results. I actually don't think the output is true to reality. If I turn off the checksum the performance gain is *only* 10%. But Valgrind makes it seem as if it is a much bigger bottleneck.

Comment: How much CPU-time in total is spent in your code? It may well be that you don't spend much time in your code in general...

Comment: @MatsPetersson 200% CPU (2 cores at 100%). It's an in-memory HTTP request between two virtual network stacks. Throughput is 19591Gbps (not over the network, just inter-thread communication).

Comment: So you are running a full web-server that processes each request? In which case I'm not surprised that your code is "not hitting in the cache" between each call - it's just that the rest of the code isn't so "concentrated", so most of the cache-misses on other things is a little here and a little there, meaning your don't see them as a big peak, but as a 0.1% here, 1% there and 0.5% somewhere else, all of which adds up, but don't stand out.

Comment: Are you really considering 0.003% of the instructions to be an issue, or is this a theoretical question? There could be many random events that cause a line to get flushed out of the I-cache every once in a while.

Answer (score 3):

replace the main loop with just:

```
const int quick_len=len/8;
const uint16_t * const the_end=b16+quick_len*4;
len -= quick_len*8;
for (; b16+4 <= the_end; b16+=4)
{
    a += b16[0];
    b += b16[1];
    c += b16[2];
    d += b16[3];
}
```

There seems no need to manually loop unroll if you use -O3

Also, the test case allowed for too much optimization since the input was static and the results unused, also printing out the result helps verify optimized versions don't break anything

Full test I used:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto start_time = steady_clock::now();
    int ret=OnesComplementSum((const uint8_t*)(s.data()+argc), s.size()-argc, 0);
    auto elapsed_ns = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(steady_clock::now() - start_time).count();

    std::cout << "loop=" << loop << " elapsed_ns=" << elapsed_ns << " = " << ret<< std::endl;

    return ret;
}
```

Comparison with theis (`CLEAN LOOP`) and your improved version (`UGLY LOOP`) and a longer test string:

```
loop=CLEAN_LOOP  elapsed_ns=8365  =  14031
loop=CLEAN_LOOP  elapsed_ns=5793  =  14031
loop=CLEAN_LOOP  elapsed_ns=5623  =  14031
loop=CLEAN_LOOP  elapsed_ns=5585  =  14031
loop=UGLY_LOOP   elapsed_ns=9365  =  14031
loop=UGLY_LOOP   elapsed_ns=8957  =  14031
loop=UGLY_LOOP   elapsed_ns=8877  =  14031
loop=UGLY_LOOP   elapsed_ns=8873  =  14031
```

Verification here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52d670039de17943

**EDIT:**

In fact the whole function can be reduced to:

```
uint32_t OnesComplementSum(const uint8_t* inData, int len, uint32_t sum)
{
  const uint16_t * b16 = reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t *>(inData);
  const uint16_t * const the_end=b16+len/2;

  for (; b16 < the_end; ++b16)
  {
    sum += *b16;
  }

  sum = (sum & uint16_t(-1)) + (sum >> 16);
  return (sum > uint16_t(-1)) ? sum - uint16_t(-1) : sum;
}
```

Which does better than the OPs with -O3 but worse with -O2:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcca1e94c2f394c7

```
loop=CLEAN_LOOP  elapsed_ns=5825  =  14031
loop=CLEAN_LOOP  elapsed_ns=5717  =  14031
loop=CLEAN_LOOP  elapsed_ns=5681  =  14031
loop=CLEAN_LOOP  elapsed_ns=5646  =  14031
loop=UGLY_LOOP   elapsed_ns=9201  =  14031
loop=UGLY_LOOP   elapsed_ns=8826  =  14031
loop=UGLY_LOOP   elapsed_ns=8859  =  14031
loop=UGLY_LOOP   elapsed_ns=9582  =  14031
```

So mileage may vary, and unless the exact architecture is known, I'd just go simpler